# How to set HTTP Header Field on AlamofireXMLRPC request?

Tags: ios, swift, http-headers, alamofire, xml-rpc

I'm trying set a HTTP Header field on my request:

```
    var params = [OdooAuth.db, OdooAuth.uid, OdooAuth.password!,"product.pricelist","search_read", [[]],["fields":["id"]] ] as [Any]
    let request = AlamofireXMLRPC.request(OdooAuth.host2!, methodName: "execute_kw", parameters: params )
    request.request?.addValue("value", forHTTPHeaderField: "HTTP_USER_AGENT")
```

But when I did write this, a error occurs:

```
Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'request' is a get-only property
```

I'm using Swift4 and [this library](https://github.com/kodlian/AlamofireXMLRPC)

Answer (score 0):

AlamofireXMLRPC provides a version of request method with optional headers dictionary. You can use that.

[image]

Example:

```
// Usage: 
let request = AlamofireXMLRPC.request(OdooAuth.host2!, methodName: "execute_kw", parameters: params, headers: ["HTTP_USER_AGENT": "value"])
```

OR

As the documentation says, you can implement `XMLRPCRequestConvertible` protocol to create your custom request.

[image]